# Ubuntu 12.04 Dropbox daemon problem

Tags: dropbox, startup-applications

I would like dropbox to autostart at startup. I installed dropbox and in dropbox preferences I set "autostart dropbox at startup".

At startup I see from system monitor that the process `dropbox` is running, the command line associated to this process is `~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd` but the dropbox daemon is not running, my files does not sync and the dropbox tray icon does not appear.

To start dropbox I have to kill this process from system monitor and start dropbox through the dash (doing this I have that the dropbox tray icon appears and dropbox works).

I have already tried:

```
$sudo apt-get remove --purge nautilus dropbox
$sudo apt-get autoremove
```

and reinstall dropbox but it did not solve the problem.

Comment: I have this problem in one of the computer at work. 12.04, the user related it to an update. I have "solved" it by adding a new command to the startup: 'sleep 40;dropbox stop;sleep 10;dropbox start'. But I'd like to find the cause and a proper fix.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your startup applications by typing startup applications in dash.

In the list of applications. choose dropbox and select edit among the buttons on the right.

Change the 'Command' part to `dropbox start -i` and save.

See image below:

[image]